# Tabs hidden in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

I used the Hide tabs option from the View < Hide Tabs , in my Sublime Text 3 editor.

In windows by pressing the alt key the tabs used to show up again.

But alt is not working in Ubuntu.
What should I press to make my tabs visible again?

Answer (score 1):

[This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672134/5987698) should answer your question. To summarize,

1. Go to **Preferences →  Key Bindings**
2. In the User keymap file, add a key combination for toggling between the visibility of tabs, as

   ```
   { "keys": ["<some key combination>"], "command": "toggle_tabs" }
   ```

Further details, including identifiers for keys, can be found in the [Sublime Text 3 documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html).

If you don't necessarily require a key combination, you can simply use **View → Show Tabs** to make them visible again.